# Android switch AP programmatically

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-wifi, wifimanager

I need to check all the available wifi and then connect to a different one which I am currently connected to.

Sample - device is connect to AP01

```
    private void switchAP(String  ssid, String  pass)) {

        WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
        conf.SSID               = "\"" + ssid + "\"";
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(pass))
            conf.wepKeys[0]     = "\"" + pass + "\"";
        conf.preSharedKey       = "\"" + pass + "\"";
        conf.wepTxKeyIndex      = 0;
        conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);
        conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.WEP40);
        conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);

        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) SyncActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);

//        List<WifiConfiguration> list = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
        List<ScanResult> list = wifiManager.getScanResults();
        for (ScanResult i : list) {

            Log.w(TAG, "WIFI LIST > " + i.SSID);

            if (i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals(ssid)) {
                wifiManager.disconnect();
                wifiManager.enableNetwork(i.networkId, true); //>i.networkId Does not work - only in List<WifiConfiguration>…
                wifiManager.reconnect();
                logMsg("WiFi connection switched to " + ssid);
                break;
            }

        }
    }
```

Then I call

```
switchAP("AP02", ""));
```

i can not connect because this **i.networkId** does not seem to work when I use ScanResult rather than WifiConfiguration.

Has anyone came across this ?
Thanks guys.

The reason why I am not using List is because the device has never been connect to this SSOD before.
and List only returns all the previews connected network.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED`.

An example code is written below for you:

```
public void WIFI_CONNECT_WIFI (String ssid, String password)
{
    WifiManager wifi_manager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    WifiConfiguration wifi_configuration = new WifiConfiguration();
    wifi_configuration.SSID              = String.format("\"%s\"", ssid);
    wifi_configuration.preSharedKey      = String.format("\"%s\"", password);


    if (WIFI_NETWORK_EXIST (wifi_configuration) == true) {
        wifi_configuration.status   = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
        wifi_configuration.priority = 40;
    }
    else {
        boolean result = wifi_manager.getConfiguredNetworks().add(wifi_configuration);
        if (result == false) {
            return;
        }
        wifi_configuration.status    = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
        wifi_configuration.priority  = 40;
        wifi_configuration.networkId = wifi_manager.addNetwork(wifi_configuration);
    }

    wifi_manager.enableNetwork(wifi_configuration.networkId, true);
    wifi_manager.saveConfiguration();
}
```

-

```
public boolean WIFI_NETWORK_EXIST (WifiConfiguration wifi_configuration)
{
    WifiManager wifi_manager = (WifiManager)getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

    for (WifiConfiguration config : wifi_manager.getConfiguredNetworks()) {

        if (wifi_configuration.SSID.equals(config.SSID)) {
            wifi_configuration.networkId = config.networkId;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And by the way, if there's a possibility to get SSID null, you are always gonna crash on your if comparison when SSID comes with null a value since you are trying to use a member function of a null value.

```
 if (i.SSID != null && i.SSID.equals(ssid)) {
     // ...
 }
```

expected stack trace is: "bla bla bla trying to use *String.equals(String)* on a null value."

You should do an inner or different if after null comparison for equals(...) comparison.